# Enabling IPv6 support on a Linksys WRT400N router

Tags: ipv6, dd-wrt, openwrt

I chatted with a Linksys support person and they said that the WRT400N doesn't have any facility for enabling IPv6.

If I were to use an alternate firmware on the router, would IPv6 become available or does IPv6 need special hardware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ipv6 does not require special hardware, if you installed DD-WRT on your router you have ipv6 options http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/IPv6

Comment: Schweet. Now let's just hope I don't brick it like my WRT54G!

Comment: Just make sure you follow the 30-30-30 reboot procedure and you'll be fine :)